# Mapbox data not appearing a lower zoom levels

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm styling a Mapbox map, and want to show mountain peak labels. I've created a layer for this, and in the "Select data" tab set the zoom range to 8-20. However on the map (and in the data select preview) the data disappears at zoom levels much higher than 8 - some peaks disappear at zoom 12, some at 10.

Is there some hidden filtering going on and if so how do I control it?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem before and it was related to the order of the layers. Some layers on top might visible at the higher zoom levels, causing the peak labels to be hidden. Try changing the layer order to put them on the top and see how that works.